# Incorrect JSON Output Using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Please excuse this question as a sign of frustration. While I understand that cause of the issue is the converting of data into different types, I can't put my finger on what's causing the result of this web service get method to be output incorrectly, that is containing backslashes.

The code below sums up the functionality of my method. I've tried different suggestions I found on these forums, some of which were in reply to similar questions I asked myself.

Data Model

```
public class WeatherResponse
{

    public class Coord
    {
        public double lon { get; set; }
        public double lat { get; set; }
    }

    public class Weather
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string main { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
    }

    public class Main
    {
        public double temp { get; set; }
        public int pressure { get; set; }
        public int humidity { get; set; }
        public int temp_min { get; set; }
        public int temp_max { get; set; }
    }

    public class Wind
    {
        public double speed { get; set; }
        public int deg { get; set; }
    }

    public class Clouds
    {
        public int all { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sys
    {
        public int type { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public double message { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public int sunrise { get; set; }
        public int sunset { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Coord coord { get; set; }
        public List<WeatherResponse> weather { get; set; }
        public string @base { get; set; }
        public Main main { get; set; }
        public int visibility { get; set; }
        public Wind wind { get; set; }
        public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
        public int dt { get; set; }
        public Sys sys { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int cod { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get(string city, string country)
    {

        string apiKey = "KEY";
        HttpWebRequest apiRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "," + country + " &appid=" + apiKey + "&units=metric") as HttpWebRequest;

        string apiResponse = "";
        using (HttpWebResponse response = apiRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            apiResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        return apiResponse;
    }
```

Result

> "{\"coord\":{\"lon\":-0.13,\"lat\":51.51},\"weather\":[{\"id\":521,\"main\":\"Rain\",\"description\":\"shower
>   rain\",\"icon\":\"09d\"}],\"base\":\"stations\",\"main\":{\"temp\":2.62,\"pressure\":991,\"humidity\":69,\"temp_min\":1,\"temp_max\":4},\"visibility\":10000,\"wind\":{\"speed\":5.1,\"deg\":90},\"clouds\":{\"all\":75},\"dt\":1548939000,\"sys\":{\"type\":1,\"id\":1414,\"message\":0.0037,\"country\":\"GB\",\"sunrise\":1548920401,\"sunset\":1548953318},\"id\":2643743,\"name\":\"London\",\"cod\":200}"

I need the code to simply retrieve weather data using the city and country received and correctly output it as JSON.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that JSON string. What's the problem?

Comment: As @PanagiotisKanavos says,  that is correct wcf json output.

Comment: Your code returns the `apiResponse` string it got from the weather service, not the `output` object. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, good catch. That line was left over from my many attempts to fix this. I've amended the code accordingly.

Comment: @croxy, when I do so, I get no result.

Comment: @Kurt what are you trying to do with this code? You are returning a string on the one hand but trying to modify the `Response` object on the other. You don't need the `Response` object in ASP.NET MVC and later. The JSON string will be returned without any issue but you may not get the content type you thought you would

Comment: You should be able to use `Content` for this (when you change the return type of your method to `IActionResult`): `return Content(apiResponse, "application/json")` should not further escape. Disclaimer: I have little experience with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert, that did the trick. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please see [Is it OK to add \[Solved\] to the title of a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question)

Comment: Please don't edit "Solved" into the title. Either answer the question with an answer (using the "Your Answer" field below), or delete the question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll duly answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution to the problem, as kindly posted by Joroen Mostert.

> You should be able to use Content for this (when you change the return
>   type of your method to IActionResult): return Content(apiResponse,
>   "application/json") should not further escape.